# Diophantus's Problem V-10

Tags: diophantine-equations, math-history

I'm a bit stuck on a problem — taken from Katz (2009) *History of Mathematics* — in which we're asked to solve Diophantus's Problem V-10 with the numbers 3 and 9.

Problem V-10: *To divide unity into two parts such that, if we add different given numbers to each, the results will be squares.*

Here are my thoughts so far:

If we arrange lengths 3, 1 and 9 on a numberline, we can see that the problem is equivalent to dividing 13 into two squares, say $x^2$ and $y^2$, such that one of the squares, say $x^2$, lies between 3 and 4.

Thinking about this geometrically, my understanding is: we are looking for a point on the circle $x^2+y^2=13$ in the region $\sqrt3<x<2$ with rational coordinates.

[image]

Have I understood the problem correctly? What would my next steps be?

Comment: Assuming "squares" is to be interpreted as "squares of rational numbers", you might note that the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 13$ can be parametrized as $$x = \frac{-2 t^2 + 6 t + 2}{t^2+1},\ y = \frac{-3 t^2 - 4 t + 3}{t^2+1}$$
and rational $t$ produces points with rational coordinates.